# Complex conjugate part of TISE

Tags: quantum-mechanics, complex-numbers

i would like to ask about complex conjugate part of this equation

[image]

why [image] ?

I know that [image]

and [image]

so [image]

Comment: $e^{+x}\times e^{-x} = e^{x-x} = e^0 = 1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Just sum the exponents! You will get $\exp[i\theta]=\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)=1$

Comment: Well said ;D +1.